# Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have declared the following in app.js

```
angular.module('adminApp', ['ngGrid','ngResource']);
```

in data.js

```
angular.module('adminApp', [])
.factory('testAccountService', function ($http) {
    var TestAccount = {
```

in GridCtrl.js

```
angular.module('adminApp',[])
    .controller('GridCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $resource, testAccountService) {
        $scope.selectedTestAccount = null;
```

I am loading my scripts like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/admin/services/Data.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/admin/controllers/GridCtrl.js"></script>
```

When I run this it gives me an error saying:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource
at Error (<anonymous>)
at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:2682:15
at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:2810:39)
at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:2687:45
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this. I am confused about how to set up the service but I can't see what's wrong:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your data.js and GridCtrl.js, you need to remove the `[]` from the `angular.module('adminApp', [])` call.

Like so:  `angular.module('adminApp')`

Also, make sure your app.js is loaded first.

Answer (score 31):

`$resource` is not part of AngularJS Core.

You have to include: **[`angular-resource.js`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-resource.js)**.

---

From [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource):

> To use `$resource` make sure you have included the `angular-resource.js` that comes in Angular package. You can also find this file on Google CDN, bower as well as at [code.angularjs.org](http://code.angularjs.org/).

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear with my question. Actually I have included the resource script. I just did not mention that. I changed my question to show it. Is there anything else you can see that may be wrong?

Comment: Do I need to always specify like this angular.module('adminApp', ['ngGrid','ngResource']);  every time I specify the angular.module or is one time enough?

Answer (score 8):

you would also need to include angular resource module definition 'ngResource' on your module defintion angular.module('adminApp', ['ngResource'])